# How can I prevent flooding in my house when it rains heavily?

Tags: drainage, flooding, sidewalk

My sidewalk slops downward from the street to the house, so when it rains heavily, water comes into the house. Not sure how to fix this situation without it costing an arm and a leg. Any suggestions?

Comment: If this is a new home, maybe this is a warranty item.

Comment: pictures would really help with this one

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean water is getting into your basement and the sidewalk connects to your foundation. My First step would be to try and seal where the sidewalk touches to foundation. There is probably a crack there where the water is getting in.  The best sealant would come in a caulk tube make sure it is flexible and made for concrete. Do not get the cheapest stuff at the store.  It may or may not work but for $10 its worth a try. A picture would help us give a better answer.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the situation but if possible I would try to raise the grade at the house and then build a swail to devert the water around or away from the foundation.  As everyone before has said. Pictures would help.  Obviously if there's a door 2" off the ground at the house you can't raise the grade.